# java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I created customized Galaxy S4 AVD with 1080x1920 for my application. I can able to run my application in that AVD. After few seconds its blinking and its throws some error like this.

```
 02-05 12:06:39.809: E/EGL_emulation(829): rcCreateWindowSurface returned 0
 02-05 12:06:39.809: E/EGL_emulation(829): tid 829: eglCreateWindowSurface(631): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
 02-05 12:06:39.819: D/AndroidRuntime(829): Shutting down VM
 02-05 12:06:39.819: W/dalvikvm(829): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829): java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1064)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:961)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:787)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1502)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 02-05 12:06:39.869: E/AndroidRuntime(829):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In after that my emulator has closed. In other default emulators my application works finely. How can i resolve this? Can anybody tell me? Thanks in advance.