# java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Tags: android, runtimeexception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_ALLOC
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.createEglSurface(HardwareRenderer.java:1245)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1062)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1877)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1256)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6652)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Yesterday, a user reported this bug in Google Play in one of my apps. Don't know why this occured. I am not sure atleast how to reproduce this. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577376/java-lang-runtimeexception-createwindowsurface-failed-egl-bad-alloc-in-android) with no answers.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar errors. The first tought was to set the layerType to software on all the WebView and all the "particular" view inside my app, but nothing changed. Now I think that this problem may be related to the complexity of the view hierarchy.Any other ideas?

Comment: Any solution to this? I have the very same problem

Comment: I wasn't even able to reproduce this.